# Broadcast Data using Alarm Manager

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am trying to send data to my parse SDK Database using Alarm Manager.

I am able to send data without Alarm manager.

My below code is not working correctly as parse sdk database is not showing updated data.

Here is my code:

**`Main Activity.java`**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.create_todo);
        setTitle(R.string.create_todo);
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

        alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES,
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, alarmIntent);
}
```

**`AlarmReceiver.java`**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        MyAsyncTask asyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();
        asyncTask.execute(new String[]{});
    }


    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject("Todo");
                parseObject.put("name", "abc");
                parseObject.save();
            }
            catch(ParseException e)
            {
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, so what isn't working exactly? Do you get errors, does nothing happen?

Comment: Nothing is happening... I am not getting any error or any exception........ New data is not added to database

Comment: Add some logger in `catch` of `ParseException`, in case it's throwing some error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register your broadcast in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Try below code:

```
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES , AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pIntent);
```

From above code, Below things will be happened.

first time Broadcast will be fired after 15 min. then it will be fired every 15 min.

Comment: I have used your code and registered my broadcast in Android Manifest file.
But Still its not working.

Comment: your code worked...done some mistake in adding in android manifest file earlier!!!    
Thanks